# Where does the code go to link View to Model and View to Controller?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, observer-pattern

I think I have a basic understanding of the idea of Model-View-Controller. I've used it in the context of server-side development, but client-side seems to be a bit different. I'm trying to write applications without a framework to get a better understanding.

My understanding of javascript MVC applications

- The event handlers for the DOM elements belonging to the View are methods on the Controller (or methods/functions defined by the View that delegate to methods on the Controller).
- The View uses the observer pattern to monitor changes in the Model

However, what I'm not sure about is where the code goes to set up these links.

It seems to me that these connections would be in the initialiser function of either the View or the Controller.

A very simple, toy example:

```
function View(model, controller) {

    model.addSubscriber(this.render);

    // code to set up DOM elements etc.

    this.button1 = document.getElementById("button1");

    this.button1.addEventListender("click", function() {
        controller.buttonhandler();
    })
}

View.prototype.render = function() {
    //
}

var view = new View(model, controller)
```

Or alternatively:

```
function Controller(model, view) {

    model.addSubscriber(view.render);

    view.button1.addEventListender("click", function() {
        this.buttonhandler();
    })

}

Controller.prototype.buttonhandler = function() {
    //
}

var controller = new Controller(model, view);
```

Is either one of these the "right" way to do MVC in client-side javascript? If not, are there advantages of one way over the other? Or am I just confusing the whole entire issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can look at my article about the subject:

- http://alexatnet.com/articles/model-view-controller-mvc-javascript

I will be happy if you like it.

Comment: Interesting. I especially like the simple way you've handled the observer pattern.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how would you deal with a situation where each todo item needs to be its own view-controller pair? (for example, if you want each todo item to have its own controls.) Presumably the view gets notified by the model when a new todo is created, and the ListView adds a new TodoView. But would you put the code that instantiates the corresponding controller instance in the View, or somewhere else? Would that violate some constraint of MVC?

Comment: I think that this question arises when you look at the UI elements as components, like "the component ToDo-item should be created multiple times" - and this does not fit into MVC, because component joins things, while MVC separates. So in this case I would rather say that Model is the list of ToDo items, Controller adds/removes/modifies items in the list and the rest is View. So the View creates components that edit individual ToDo-items and do not care of the internal implementation of the component. There may be MVC inside it as well or may be not - who cares?